# transfering fixed words in multiline textbox in visual basic to seperate single line textboxes

Tags: vb.net, string

I am having problem in visual basic textbox  so my actual problem is i have a **Multiline** textbox1 containing FirstName="JOHN" in one line and LastName="SMITH" in the newline and i want to transfer only JOHN in separate **singleline** textbox2 and SMITH in other **singleline** textbox3.
i want this to happen on click of copy button.
The lefthanside of the textbox1 like FirstName,LastName remains constant whereas the rightside like JOHN,SMITH are changing in nature.
I have created a separate function and i have tried so far as

```
Public Class Form1
Dim itemsInTextBox As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim firstName As String = itemsInTextBox(0).Split("=".ToCharArray)(1)
Dim secondName As String = itemsInTextBox(1).Split("=".ToCharArray)(1)
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = firstName
    TextBox3.Text = secondName
End Sub
```

End Class

here's the link to screenshot of what i want to accomplish.
http://tinypic.com/r/2mcev5w/8
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could separate the text from the textbox by new lines. Something like:

```
Dim itemsInTextBox as String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf.toCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim firstName as String = itemsInTextBox(0).Split("=".toCharArray)(1)
Dim secondName as String = itemsInTextBox(1).Split("=".toCharArray)(1)
```

This is assuming your lines in the textbox are separated by new lines. If it is separated by something else, just put that in the split method. This also keeps the quotation marks (do you want this?)

EDIT: for setting other textboxes

```
TextBox2.Text = firstName
TextBox3.Text = secondName
```

[image: Working form]

EDIT2: You have to create those variables on button click. If you do it globally, it will be run before your TextBox1 exists.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim itemsInTextBox As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim firstName As String = itemsInTextBox(0).Split("=".ToCharArray)(1)
    Dim secondName As String = itemsInTextBox(1).Split("=".ToCharArray)(1)
    TextBox2.Text = firstName
    TextBox3.Text = secondName
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried your code but there was error in this line[ Dim itemsInTextBox as String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbcrlf.toCharArray)] saying :-NULL EXCEPTION WAS UNHANDED BY YOUR CODE ,  how can i solve this error.

Comment: Sorry, that was because I forgot to remove empty entries. See my edit (`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`)

Comment: thanks man but its still not working,shows error at the first line.my friend tried method using delimeter but still could not do it.Really tired of this.this is part of our project.please help solve this or the other .it would be really helpfull.

Comment: Is TextBox1 blank when you run this code? If you add a breakpoint at this location you can see what you are trying to split.

Comment: i couldn't make to run, i the error is during compilation it says:NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code and object code not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @manishbhattarai It seems to be working for me. Either `TextBox1` is  nothing or the text is nothing. And when you try to reference nothing it throws this error.

Comment: i have added the added the exact code what i have used,in my question section section.and i didnt understant what u mean by making the textbox1 empty.because its not compiling

Comment: should we be entering the value in textbox1 after it has been run?

Comment: @manishbhattarai Ah. The issue was where you have declared your variables. This should be done in the button event. Check my edit.

Comment: yee it worked thanks a lot .finally made it to work.

Comment: @manishbhattarai Sweet! If you could accept my answer that'd be great.

Comment: obviously i'm going to use it.once again thanks man it was nice knowing you

Comment: @manishbhattarai I mean accept it on this website since it worked :)

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to vote up,if thats what you mean.i am new to this site so i will surely do if i can

Answer (score 0):

Your sample and your description are different. In your sample you use FIRSTNAME=JOHN and in your description you use first-name="john" which are very different.

Lets use your sample. Your test should look like this.

```
TextBox2.Text = GetValue("FIRSTNAME=JOHN" & vbcrlf & "LASTNAME=SMITH") 
TextBox3.Text = GetValue("FIRSTNAME=JOHN" & vbcrlf & "LASTNAME=SMITH")
```

Of you try it like this, you will see it's not returning the right information.

You'll have to split each line and then split these line again with the = sign like you did.

```
Function GetValue(ByVal data As String, ByVal key As String) As String

    Dim lines() As String = data.Split(Chr(10))

    For Each line As String In lines
        line = line.Trim()
        Dim subData() As String = line.Split("="c)

        If subData(0) = key Then
            Return subData(1)
        End If
    Next

    Return ""
End Function

Sub Main()

    Dim data As String

    data = "FIRSTNAME=JOHN" & Environment.NewLine & "LASTNAME=SMITH"

    Console.WriteLine(GetValue(data, "FIRSTNAME"))
    Console.WriteLine(GetValue(data, "LASTNAME"))
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm  sorry  i was not clear with my question. so i have added a link to the screenshot of what i want to accomplish.Hope that clears my problem.thanks for your effort.

Comment: @manishbhattarai it's does like your screenshot but instead of printing in a textbox it prints in the console

Comment: so how can i make it to print in the textbox.i am really new to the visual basic and have to complete this project.in trying your code its not showing any responses.should i add something.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the declaration of the itemsList into the sub for the copy.
EDIT:  Also need to move the declaration of the strings

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim itemsInTextBox As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim firstName As String = itemsInTextBox(0).Split("=".ToCharArray)(1)
    Dim secondName As String = itemsInTextBox(1).Split("=".ToCharArray)(1)
    TextBox2.Text = firstName
    TextBox3.Text = secondName
End Sub
```